# Explanation of new options in IIS 10 bindings window

Tags: https, windows-server-2022, iis-10

as above, can someone please either explain the new options in the IIS 10 HTTPS site bindings options (flags) or provide a link that explains exactly what they do and any impact on a site? I have done a search online but could not find anything that really assists with all of them. I am referring to these options:
[image: IIS 10 options]

Comment: The three on the left are all SSL/TLS related, while the two on the right are HTTP protocol related. Usually you won't need to know/change them unless you hit an actual issue, but if you do want to learn of them I believe search engines know them very well. You might try different set of keywords.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your reply, however, despite the assertion that search engines "know them very well" I have not yet found a site that does, in fact, explain each and every one in detail. I would not have asked here if I had found such a site, hence my attempting to request the knowledge of more experienced persons on Server Fault. Having said that, I will accept that your reply will most likely be the the most appropriate one I will receive, given recent experiences here on Server Fault and associated websites. I therefore thank you again and will attempt to find the answer elsewhere.